# Verify the presence of an inflection point

Tags: functions

$$y = f (x) = \sqrt[3]{x + 1}$$
NB: the root is cubic - index 3

The point that I have to check the presence of the inflection point or vertical tangent is $(-1.0)$
Could you explain the steps to do?
Thank You.

Comment: If it exists, a necessary condition of an inflection point $p$ is that $f''(p)=0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a vertical tangent, you take the derivative and check if there are any values of x where the derivative does not exist.

The derivative for this one is 1/3*(x+1)^(-2/3). So there is a vertical tangent where x = -1.

For the point of inflection, take the second derivative, and check for places where it is 0 or undefined, then check if the second derivative has changed at that point.

Second derivative:  -2/9*(x+1)^(-5/3). So possible point of inflection at x = -1. Second derivative changes from positive to negative at x = -1, so this is a point of inflection.

Answer (score 1):

Calculate the gradient function $\frac{dy}{dx}$ then a necessary but not sufficient condition for the existence of an inflection point at $p$ is:
\begin{equation}
\left.\frac{d^{2}y}{dx^{2}} \right|_{p}=0
\end{equation}